# Video playing over and over again as background iOS

Tags: video, swift2, ios9

In my app the welcoming screen will have a video as a background instead of an image and there will be buttons and subviews over it. I tried this but only a blank video showed up with the toolbar to pause and play. I would rather have the video looping though with no toolbar or anything, just itself. What's the best way to go about this?

Thanks!

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

class CreateAccountViewController: UIViewController {

var url = "MYURL"
var moviePlayer = AVPlayerViewController()

//label properties and button go here

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

//        let videoURL = NSURL(string: "MYURL")
//        let player = AVPlayer(URL: videoURL!)
//        let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
//        playerLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
//        self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
//        player.play()

    let URL = NSURL(string: url)
    let player = AVPlayer(URL: URL!)
    let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()

    playerController.player = player
    self.addChildViewController(playerController)
    self.view.addSubview(playerController.view)
    playerController.view.frame = self.view.frame

    player.play()

}

}
```

Comment: I would suggest using the MPMoviePlayerController, I have some old Obj-C code if you want to convert it to Swift?

Comment: I tried that but Xcode told me it was deprecated. I'll take a look at it and try just in case I suppose. Thanks!

Comment: It may well be, I haven't used it for a while.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when changing from `MPMoviePlayerViewController` to `AVPlayer`.

You should do the following (Sorry for the Objective - C code, not to sharp on Switf at the moment):

1. Register (in `viewDidLoad` or in any other comfortable place) to `AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification`:

   ```
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]  addObserver:self selector:@selector(stopVideo:) name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:[player currentItem]];
   ```
2. Implement `stopVideo:`,which will be called upon the above notification, where you unregister for the above notifications as well as setting your player to nil so it has nothing to play:

   ```
   -(void)stopVideo:(NSNotification *) notification
   {
       //any other relevant code goes here
       player = nil;
       [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:[player currentItem]];
   }
   ```

This worked for me, hope it helps.